# Adding the <location> tag to web.config causes website folders to be inaccessible. How to fix?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-10

I've added an application beneath my `main` website which is a newer version of the main website.  The sub application named `V2` will be used to preview changes to the main website.

In order to access V2 from the main website, I need to modify the `web.config` to enclose both the `<system.web>` and `<system.webServer>` tags in the `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">` tag.

The V2 website runs as expected (i.e. `//main/V2`) but all of the sub-folders in both main and V2 can't be read.  The styles and images are in folders which are inaccessible. It seems like a permissions issue.  The application is configured to allow all users full access to the root and all sub-directories.

```
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

What do I have to do to make all the sub-directories accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions issue was caused by the `<location>` tag in the `web.config`. The `<system.webServer><validation>` tag did not like being wrapped in the `<location>` tag so I pulled it out;
like this.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>

<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    ...
```

Now all of the folders are readable.

Answer (score 0):

What error message did you get when you access the subfolder? When you apply configuration in 
`<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">`, subfolder will not be applied.

IIS will specify  `<add accessType="Allow" users="*" />` in applicationhost.config by default. So if you have specify    `<allow users="*" />` in web.config, you have to remove the default setting in applicationhost.config to avoid duplicated key error.

When you only apply `inheritInChildApplications="false"`, `<allow users="*" />`will only work on root `"location='.'"` level. And no authorization rule has been specified for these sub folders. Then you may get 401.2 when you access these folder.

Please set authorization rule for these path.

To troubleshooting permission issue, please enable Failed request tracing. It will tell you where the permission should be granted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: `Error 500` is returned when resources (images and styles) in sub-folders are accessed.

The applicationHost.config file does not have the `<add accessType="Allow" users="*" />` tag.

I did try setting an authorization rule for the images and styles folders, but it did not seem to help.

The issue occurs only when I wrap `<system.webServer>` with the 
<location inheritInChildApplications="false"> tag.  Resources become
available when I toggle false to true.

I'm going to enable Failed request tracing as you suggested.  Thanks.